# Best HTML structure for Ajax links

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, onclick

When using javascript to assign onclick handlers to HTML `<a>` tags, I have a specific question when it comes to the use of Ajax - what's the best way to get the URL to the ajax request?  Should I use `this.href` or code it into the handler function itself?

Consider the following link:

```
<a id="link" href="http://mysite.com/getData.php">Get Data</a>
```

Then, the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() { 
   // Send ajax request
}
```

I like using `this.href` inside the handler but I'm worried about a user who clicks the link before domready fires and the links are activated.  Is it better to use `href="javascript:void(0);"` in the HTML and then construct the URL in the handler itself?  This way, the link would do nothing unless it's activated.  What's the best-practice here?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it from this perspective: how would your page architecture hold up if no JS was enabled?

Your application should be responsive to user input under any circumstances, and should not rely on implicit assumptions about whether users will have Javascript-enabled browsers. Sounds ridiculous, right? Well, I have plenty of clients who work for huge corps where the desktop configs are all locked down, so everyone's running IE6 with some incredibly strict settings.

Therefore, the href attribute of your anchor tag should point to the location where you want users to go if they do not have Javascript enabled (you should have a fall-back in place for your AJAX functionality that will basically do the same thing). In your onclick handler you should specify the URI for the AJAX call.

When it's all said and done, users who have JS enabled (which will be the majority) will hit your onclick handler in which you have the URI for your AJAX XHR call, and users who do not have JS enabled will be redirected to another page that achieves an equivalent result.

Comment: Man, I'm trying to save my votes for questions, but I just had to +1 this. Thank you for a voice of sanity in a world too-crowded with `href="#"` and `href="javascript:..."` chaff.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks - I do agree with that concept.  But let's say I have 100 ajax links that differ only in their URLs, should I really be writing 100 handlers?

Comment: @Brian Well, yes and no. You should refactor code that's common to your 100 AJAX handlers into a single function that takes the URI as a parameter. But, yes, you will likely have to write 100 different onclick handlers that call that function, if you choose to follow my advice.

Comment: Very interesting.  And how about passing query string parameters?  Would you stick them in other attributes of the tag (or hide them in the DOM somewhere) and parse them from within the handler as well?

Comment: It honestly would depend on context. If you have the values available when you call your refactored "doAjax(someUri)" method, then I'd say construct the URI with the query string and pass it on to your doAjax method. If the parameters come from elsewhere, then you'd have to do the URI construction in your doAjax method instead.